# Youtube API access Issue

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Our scripting team have built a script using Youtube API, to upload videos. Around 8-10 users have access to upload the videos using API, simultaneously.

The users are experiencing an error randomly. It shows that the video upload has failed.

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable

```
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}

"ERROR VideoEntityManagerImpl:? - Video not Uploaded to youtube

INFO LoggingOutInterceptor:? - Outbound Message"
```

They retried and video is uploaded successfully.

Here is the twist: post the successful upload in the 2nd attempt they get a notification in Youtube that there are duplicate videos.

This is a concerning issue as we are in production, and everything was working fine earlier. We encountered this issue last week.

Is there a way where I can get more logs for this to understand the issue better? What can be done to eliminate this?

Comment: Just following up. Does anyone has any insights about this..?

Answer (score 0):

This happens occasionally. Most likely it happens when the back-end server is too busy. It looks like your upload script may not be using the **ResumableUpload** class capability to resume a failed upload. Maybe the API version you are using does not contain the **ResumableUpload** class. Using the **ResumableUpload** class, when you receive a back-end server error, you can resume the upload from the point of failure. In the [google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples) repository on GitHub, there are two .NET examples showing how to use **.UploadAsync** and **.ResumeAsync** methods of the **ResumableUpload** class. Though these examples are .NET, you should be able to learn enough from them to enhance your script to allow for resuming upon experiencing a back-end server error. Last night, I uploaded three 30 minute videos during which my application did several **.ResumeAsync** method calls to successfully resume after a back-end server error.

There are also **.Upload** and **.Resume** methods if you wish to use synchronous calls.

From HTTP Status Codes Documentation:
503 = HTTP_STATUS_SERVICE_UNAVAIL - The service is temporarily overloaded.